# Does the following series of transformations of inequalities holds?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, inequality, logarithms, transformation

I am to calculate limit of the function $f(x,y)$ i am trying to apply squeeze theorem. Is the following series of transformations of this inequality correct? If not how to do this correctly? i.e. are those inequalities true or false? They should hold for all positive numbers.
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\ln \left(1+x^3+y^3 \right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ln \left(1+x^3+y^3 \right)}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \left(x+y
\right)}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} }{1}$$

Comment: Are you asking "are the following inequalities true" or something else? I don't understand "series of transformations of inequalities".  Also, for which values of $x,y$ should these hold?

Comment: Yes i am asking whether each of those inequalities is true or false. They should hold obviously for positive numbers because of the logarithm. If something is still unclear please let me know i will try to explain this differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your last inequality is equivalent to the inequality
\begin{equation}
x + y \leq x^2 + y^2 \quad \forall x, y > 0,
\end{equation}
which is false (e.g. take $x, y = \frac{1}{2}$).

Perhaps use the following:

- For any $\alpha > 0$, $\ln(1 + \alpha) \leq \alpha$.
- $x^3 + y^3 \leq (x^2 + y^2)(x + y) \leq (x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}$, provided $x, y > 0$.

You should find $f(x,y) \leq x^2 + y^2$, $\forall x, y > 0$.